# Android - Is there a way to switch on native memory user interface in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-management, ddms

I've been keeping a tab on native memory through command line. But, it would be of great helpful if I could see the native memory user interface, under DDMS view, in Eclipse. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for asking a nice question. However I don't think there is any such tool so far. Google guys must do something regarding it since memory leaks in Native have more harsh effects on App since the app crashes without even telling you when and why .

Comment: @anDroider Thanks. It would also help in understanding the statistical data. Secondly, I think native memory space is allocated inside heap memory, for higher android versions. So this issue is solved for versions through and above Gingerbread. Please Guide me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I meant above Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0):

You can fully customize your Perspective (in this case DDMS) if you go under "Window -> Show View" you can add all the views you want to your perspective.